# Prove the inequality based on an infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Define
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{nx^n}{1-x^n}.$$
It is easy to see that this series converges for $x\in(-1,1).$
Now we are asked to show that $(1-x)^2f(x)\geq x,$ for $x\in[0,1).$

I tried defining $g(x)=(1-x)^2f(x)-x$ and differentiating $g$ but could not proceed further.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write the inequality as

$$f(x) \geqslant \frac{x}{(1-x)^2}.$$

You might know a series representation of the right hand side.

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nx^n$ brilliant!